# How can I do store multidimensional array base on name in Laravel collection?

Tags: laravel, collections

In image you can see name and I want to store on base of name

[image]

Array index 0 & 2 have the same name. And I want to store same name in one array

Like This:

```
Josue Koepp DDS => {
            id=>2,
            item_name=>"Domenic Labadie"
           },
           {
            id=>0,
            item_name=>"Prof. Jakayla Willms"
           }
    }
```

Comment: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1344 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#1350 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"item_name": "Prof. Jakayla Willms"
      
      +"name": "Josue Koepp DDS"
    }

Comment: Please don't paste code like this in the comments, hard to read. Instead, [edit] your question and paste relevant data there. Thanks

Comment: `->groupBy('name')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby)

```
$collection = collect([
    ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
    ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
    ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
]);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('account_id');

$grouped->toArray();

/*
    [
        'account-x10' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
        ],
        'account-x11' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
        ],
    ]
*/
```

In your case:

```
$lists = $lists->groupBy('name')->toArray();
```